# Expanding wildcard in batch

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have written a Java program for linux and windows.
To start the program, I use the following code in linux:

abc.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /opt/AudiobookConverter/AudiobookConverter.jar "$@"
```

The "$@" will expand any wildcard I may throw at it.
So, if I want my program to process all .mp3-files in a certain directory, I just call abc.sh *.mp3 and it does its magic.

Under Windows, I have the following code, which is supposed to do the same:
abc.bat:

```
java -jar C:\AudiobookConverter\AudiobookConverter.jar "%*"
```

But when I call abc.bat *.mp3, it will pass *.mp3 to the java program, instead of a list of the files ending in .mp3.

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix this?

Greetings,
AHahn94

Comment: where abc.sh file? put it in question

Comment: There's no magic in batch, you'll need a batch magician ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "files="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%*" ') do set "files=!files! %%a"
java -jar C:\AudiobookConverter\AudiobookConverter.jar "%files%"
```

The `setlocal` command opens a local environment with `delayed expansion` invoked. The `dir` command lists files (names only - no directorynames), the `for` assigns the entire list-line to `%%a`, and each name is appended to the environment variable `files` using the `delayed expansion` syntax to access the run-time value.

Once the `files` variable has been established, conventional syntax may be used to pass it to the `java` command.

Comment: I had to change `"files=!files! %%a"` to `"files=!files! "%%a""` and I had to remove the quotes from the last `"%files%"`, so that names with whitespaces are in quotes, but else: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: The original solution would create the output `"var1 var2 var3"`, which Java would interprete as 1 String instead of 3, but I needed `"var1" "var2" "var3" ...`, so that Java recognizes the variables as single Strings and so that whitespaces in the variables are recognized as part of the variable. Therefore the modification.

Comment: Wasn't quite sure about Java's view of the world. All fixed, then!